# How to allow free-form JSON data within Mongoose documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using [Mongoose ODM](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/model-definition.html) to partially validate models before they are stored to MongoDB.

Is it possible to relax Mongoose schemata so that a given part of the document is not validated? I have tried to the following:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    user_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    freeform_data: {},
});
```

For instance if I set the contents to:

```
{
   user_id: '123456',
   freeform_data: {
      dataitem1: 'a',
      dataitem2: 'b',
      items: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
   }
}
```

Then only `user_id` is stored, which makes perfectly sense security-wise.

How can I disable mongoose's validation for this field?

I am using this application only for prototyping purposes so I don't care about security right now (I just want to prototype).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you modify the contents of a [`Mixed`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) field like freeform_data, you need to notify Mongoose that you've changed its value by calling `markModified(path)` on the modified document or a subsequent `save()` call won't save it.

For example:

```
user.freeform_data = { foo: 'bar' };
user.markModified('freeform_data');
user.save();
```

Comment: Thank you so much - exactly what I was looking for! Also found some discussion around this topic: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/822

Answer (score 0):

**Mongeese**
: a mongoose multi-database helper/hack module
https://github.com/donpark/mongeese

Disclaimer: I was looking to connect to two MongoDB instances in the same app and gave up. So I haven't tried it.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.

Comment: How is this related to the original question? I'm ready to upvote this if you provide a relevant explanation.